# Using rvest or RSelenium to Scrape Table

Tags: r, json, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

**The goal:** Scrape the table from the following website using R.

**The website:** https://evanalytics.com/mlb/models/teams/advanced

**What has me stuck:**
I use rvest to automate most of my data gathering process, but this particular site seems to be out of rvest's scope of work (or at least beyond my level of experience). Unfortunately, it doesn't immediately load the table when the page opens. I have tried to come up with a solution via RSelenium but have been unsuccessful in finding the right path to the table (RSelenium is brand new to me). After navigating to the page and pausing for a brief period to allow the table to load, what's next?

**What I have so far:**

```
library("rvest")
library("RSelenium")

url <- "https://evanalytics.com/mlb/models/teams/advanced"

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr="192.168.99.100", port=4445L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(10)
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without Selenium by creating an html_session so as to pick up the required php session id to pass in cookies. You additionally need an user-agent header. With session in place you can then make a POST xhr request to get all the data. You need a json parser to handle the json content within response html.

You can see the params info in one of the script tags:

```js
function executeEnteredQuery() {
    var parameterArray = {
        mode: 'runTime',
        dataTable_id: 77
    };
    $.post('/admin/model/datatableQuery.php', {
            parameter: window.btoa(jQuery.param(parameterArray))
        },
        function(res) {
            processdataTableQueryResults(res);
        }, "json");
}
```

You can encode the string yourself for params:

```
base64_enc('mode=runTime&dataTable_id=77')
```

---

**R:**

```
require(httr)
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)
require(jsonlite)

headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
body = list('parameter' = 'bW9kZT1ydW5UaW1lJmRhdGFUYWJsZV9pZD03Nw==') # base64 encoded params for mode=runTime&dataTable_id=77
session <- html_session('https://evanalytics.com/mlb/models/teams/advanced', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers))

p <- session %>% rvest:::request_POST('https://evanalytics.com/admin/model/datatableQuery.php', body = body)%>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node('p') %>% 
  html_text()

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(p)
df <- data$dataRows$columns
print(df)
```

---

**Py:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

body = {'parameter': 'bW9kZT1ydW5UaW1lJmRhdGFUYWJsZV9pZD03Nw=='} # base64 encoded params for mode=runTime&dataTable_id=77

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://evanalytics.com/mlb/models/teams/advanced')
    r = s.post('https://evanalytics.com/admin/model/datatableQuery.php')
    data = r.json()
    cols = [th.text for th in bs(data['headerRow'], 'lxml').select('th')]
    rows = [[td.text for td in bs(row['dataRow'], 'lxml').select('td')] for row in data['dataRows']]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = cols)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well!

The part I'm having trouble reverse engineering is the base64 string. Where did this come from?

Comment: It looks like the site has added a login, which is free, that has caused this script to no longer work in the same way. Is there a way to retrieve this same information again with the site update?

Comment: I can't remember about the base64. I assume I found the encoded string within an xhr on the page and decoded it to see what it was doing or used experience that sometimes you need a base64 encoded body for a POST.

Comment: For the new site you may need to perform an initial authorisation request (perhaps basic auth?) You should be able to see by logging into a free account and monitoring the web traffic. Otherwise, I guess look for an alternate source ideally an API.

Answer (score 0):

Little short on time so just pointing you to html source code, from which you could extract the table with r vest.

```
  remDr$navigate(url)
  html <-remDr$getPageSource()
## this will get you html of the page, form here 
## just extract the table as you would with rvest
```